# BottomSheetDialogFragment is collapsed when I scroll down it

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet, android-bottomsheetdialog

I am developing an android app using Jetpack Compose.

The app is a legacy app, and I should add a new BottomSheet.

So my BottomSheet is like:

```kotlin
class MyBottomSheet: BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setContent {
                MyTheme(colors = getThemeColor()) {
                    MyBottomSheetScreen()
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

It contains Composable function.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyBottomSheetScreen(
    onBackPressed: () -> Unit
) {
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .fillMaxHeight(0.9F),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 20.dp, topEnd = 20.dp),
        color = MyTheme.colors.surface
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            content()
        }
    }
}
```

It shows BottomSheet correctly.
But I can only scroll up, when I scroll down the bottom sheet is collapsed.
What I want to do is scroll down, and when it reached the top, the bottom sheet should be collapsed.

I added the `Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())` in the BottomSheet Screen content.

I think that this issue is caused by using "Jetpack compose & View BottomSheet collaboration".

Is there any good solution?

Comment: add  .nestedScroll(rememberNestedScrollInteropConnection()) in your surface modifier